# Extract data from external database Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla

I used [this tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/Connecting_to_an_external_database) to connect to a external database in my Joomla website.

I think that **I managed to connect successfully to the database**, but when I tried to use the data it returns an empty white page.

This is the code which I am using if the Table was in the joomla database:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true); 

$query->select(array('*'))
->from($db->quoteName('orders'))
->where($db->quoteName('manufacturer') . ' IS NOT NULL')
$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();

echo '<table class="table table-striped">';

foreach ($results as $row)
{

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td class="first">'. $row->manufacturer .'</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row->type. '.</td>';
echo '<td>' . ($row->power+0) . ' kW</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row->rpm. ' мин.<sup>-1</sup></td>';
echo '</tr>';

}

echo '</table>';
```

How should I modify it, so I can have this simple table but from an external database?

Answer (score 0):

The following in your code...

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
```

...will connect to the Joomla database, and not to the external database. Check the guide again and see how the external connection is made.

In any case, a white page is a sign of a fatal error somewhere. Check your logs or enable error reporting to see where the error comes from.

Also, make sure that you are actually in the Joomla context (e.g. the Joomla environment has loaded) if you want to use Joomla's functions.

Comment: Exactly 

you must use JDatabaseDriver->getInstance method.

Answer (score 0):

Use This code

```
<?php
$option = array(); //prevent problems

$option['driver']   = 'mysql';            // Database driver name
$option['host']     = 'localhost';    // Database host name
$option['user']     = 'root';       // User for database authentication
$option['password'] = '';   // Password for database authentication
$option['database'] = 'database';      // Database name
$option['prefix']   = 'abc_';             // Database prefix (may be empty)

$db = JDatabaseDriver::getInstance( $option );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust `->where($db->quoteName('manufacturer') . ' IS NOT NULL')`
to have a semi-colon at the end. 
That will help with the PHP error.